# ZuulFilter is not invoked

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I use:

- spring-boot 2.1.2.RELEASE
- spring-cloud Greenwich.RELEASE

Zuul dependency:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul'
```

I'm invoking a microservice from another one using zuul and load balanced rest template:

```
restTemplate.postForEntity("http://image/api/image", imageDto, ImageDto.class)
```

The request reaches the downstream service but the `Authorization` header (I tried with different ones) is not being set in the ZullFilter:

```
public class ZuulAuthFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    public String filterType() {
        return PRE_TYPE;
    }

    public int filterOrder() {
        return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER - 1;
    }

    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        String authorizationValue = ctx.getRequest().getHeaders(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER).nextElement();
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, authorizationValue);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've also created a filter `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public ZuulAuthFilter zuulAuthFilter() {
    return new ZuulAuthFilter();
}
```

Here is my zuul configuration:

```
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  ribbon:
    eager-load:
      enabled: true
```

It looks like the filter is not being invoked at all. I've added `System.exit(0)` to each overriden filter method and the app is still running.

I've annotated the Application class with `@EnableZuulProxy`

What am I missing? Why the filter might not be invoked? Should it be invoked in my case at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm invoking a microservice from another one using zuul proxy.

According to [the sources](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) it seems that Zuul filters are invoked from *ZuulServlet*. Spring Cloud *ZuulController* only wraps *ZuulServlet*. So there is no way to invoke Zuul filter chain before calling *restTemplate* out of the box. And Zuul isn't intended for internal microservice communication.

Comment: 1) The request is created within the app in the middle of the chain by invoking `restTemplate.postForEntity("http://image/api/image", imageDto, ImageDto.class)` where Zuul automatically changes `http://image` to a URL taken from Eureka. So I need to push the 'Authorization' header from current request to the one being created by Zuul. 2) In my case the filter is marked as `@Bean` in a class annotated by `@SpringBootApplication` that inherits the `@Configuration` annotation. 3) A monolith app invokes service A which then invokes service B. The Auth header is lost in app A before reaching B.

Comment: Anton, you wrote that you are invoking `restTemplate.postForEntity("http://image/api/image", imageDto, ImageDto.class)` . It looks like you are using LoadBalanced RestTemplate. It means that you're invoking your targeting service directly from your client to your destination without Zuul. If you want to access your target API via Zuul, you need to invoke `http://zuulipaddress:port/image/api/image". LoadBalanaced RestTemplate resolves IP addresses with Eureka by itself and can invoke target API without the help of Zuul. I guess that that's why your filter is not invoked.